# Is there any way to get list of searched or sorted bootstrap table data?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm using bootstrap table to select data for my form and but I have a problem to select from sorted or searched table is there any way to get data? Or I should sort or search in my list by my own?

This is how I get the row:

```
var row = allData[$("#tableId .selected").index()];
```

That I think it was the worst idea!!

And this is where table fills:

```
$('#tableId').bootstrapTable({
       columns: columnsStyle,
       data: allData
});
```

result is a list of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a trick that it works but if there is still a way using bootstrap I appreciate it.

I added a column to append an id to every row as below:

```
columnsStyle = [
    {
        field: "dataRowIndex",
        title: "",
        class: "d-none",
        searchable: false
    },
    otherColumns...
]
```

then I filled it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
    allData[i]["dataRowIndex"] = i;
}
```

And get the selected row using code below:

```
var row = allData[parseInt($("#tableId .selected .rowIndex").html())];
```